# TYPO3 Powermail 2.x many forms and hidden fields

Tags: forms, typo3, hidden, powermail

I am in a TYPO3 project with Powermail 2.x and there are different forms (created in the backend). Every form needs the same hidden fields, is tehre a way to create this needed fields once and use it in any form? Does someone know something similar or exactly something like this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with powermail there is no option to add the fields from another form on the same page or from another page.

I would suggest to complete the first Powermail form with all required fields and then copy it. Once you copy the Powermail plugin element and paste it on another page, the included Powermail form and all fields are also copied.

It's not exactly what you were looking for, but simple and effective.